# How to get the id of an iframe attribut

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I embedded a spreedsheet ethercalc on my redmine issue page in an iframe, when I tried to pull up some spreedsheet attributes, I constate that the DOM of my current page is different from the DOM of iframe.
There is the code inspector of my page and my iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Bug #17: dddd - ERP PROJECT - Redmine</title>
<meta name="description" content="Redmine" />
<meta name="keywords" content="issue,bug,tracker" />
............

............
<div id="my_sheet"  >
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.4:8000/qFoGnxzozw" width="1000" height="500" style="display: none" id="sheet">frame content.</iframe>
#document
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>
<base target="_blank"/>
<title>EtherCalc - Share the URL to your friends and edit together!</title>
.............
.............
<body onresize="if (typeof doresize != 'undefined') doresize();">
<div id="msg" style="position:absolute;right:15px;top: 8px; bottom: 80px; display: none">
<textarea id="msgtext" style="margin-top:10px;width:110px;height:100%;"></textarea><br>
<form id="msgform">
<input type="text" id="msgout" name="msgout" style="width: 110px">
<br>
<input type="submit" style="font-size:x-small;" value="Add a line" onclick="val = document.getElementById('msgout').value; if (/\S/.test(val)) {SocialCalc.Callbacks.broadcast('chat', {msg: val}); addmsg(val, false); document.getElementById('msgout').value = ''}; return false"><br>
</form>
</div>
<div id="tableeditor">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
</div> 

</div>
```

for example i need to pull the tableeditor attribut
How can i do this job please ??
[Here is my view to more explain my need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVWxD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found you explanation a little confusing, however, from what I understand you want to get an element from the iframe by its id. If so, using jQuery you can get the content of an iframe by using `$('iframe').contents()` [see here.](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

From which you could then chain the selectors as per normal.

**However, this can only be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.**

So based on you saying that your main page and your iframe src are different, there is no way I know of using jQuery to complete this.

Comment: Thanks for this information, apparently my iframe is on different domain as the  main page

Comment: No worries. If it answers your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer. Good luck with your endeavours.